# changing block to inline of an <li> tag makes list-style-type hidden and I cant see after adding list-style-type:circle; and padding , margin

Tags: css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
 <li>HTML</li>
 <li>CSS</li>
 <li>JavaScript</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected Output
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8b8u.png)

```
when I add display : inline of <li> then
```

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
li {
  display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>HTML</li>
  <li>CSS</li>
  <li>JavaScript</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

[output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8b8u.png)

And my question is after adding padding , margin , line-style-type : circle; I didn't get Expected output ( The

missing )
***Maybe Using flex I get desired output but what happens in here !!!***

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some class names is better to add  style directly into li and ul
Using Flex u need to give list style also.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.list li {
display: inline;
padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list">
<li>HTML</li>
<li>CSS</li>
<li>JavaScript</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```